# DBNull From DataSet Cast to Nullable Constructor

Tags: c#, dbnull

I have a constructor with a signature that looks something like:

```
public Something(UInt64 uid, UInt64? parentUniqueId)
{
    // ...
}
```

The constructor is called with the result of a database retrieval. It is possible that the `parentUniqueId` returns as `DBNull`.

Currently, the calling code looks something like:

```
var s = new Something(uid: Convert.ToUint64(row[0]), ConvertTo.Unit64(row[1]))
```

That doesn't work, so I tried (in the second cast) to do `(Unit64?)row[1]`; but, that is freaking out.

The challenge here is that `Something` is a base class that accepts "specified" arguments, e.g. `Unit64` and it is being called from an inheriting class that accepts a `DataRow`. So, you can imagine:

```
public SomethingSpecific(DataRow row)
    : base(
        uid: Convert.ToUInt64(row[0]))
        // etc...
     )
{ }
```

Is this possible in one line? How would I handle the `DBNull` conversion?

Comment: Why not using or mapper?

Comment: What do you want to store if the result is row[0] contains a null?

Comment: The dataset's default value is dbnull, is it possible to change the default to something that makes your code happy?

Comment: @CF5 just NULL, if possible

Comment: I'd go with something like:     

var s = new Something(uid: Convert.IsDBNull(row[0]) ? null : Convert.ToUint64(row[0]), ConvertTo.Unit64(row[1]));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own convert method like this:

```
public static class MyConvert
{
    public static UInt64? ToUInt64OrNull(object value)
    {
        if(Convert.IsDBNull(value) || value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt64(value);
        }

    }
}
```

`null` and `DBNull` are two very different values. So you have to explicitly handle them both.

Then use it like this:

```
var s = new Something(uid: Convert.ToUInt64(row[0]), MyConvert.ToUInt64OrNull(row[1]))
```

It is assumed that `row[0]` will never be `null` or `DBNull`, but that `row[1]` can be `DBNull` and will be passed as null to the constructor then.

This is how you would use it when writing your child class:

```
public SomethingSpecific(DataRow row)
    : base(
        uid: Convert.ToUInt64(row[0]),
        parentUniqueId: MyConvert.ToUInt64OrNull(row[1])
        // etc...
     )
{ }
```

Comment: This feels a bit more robust. Do you think it is necessary to account for `null` or do you think I could go with a one line approach akin to that posted by the other answer? Particularly considering the constructor of `SomethingSpecific`.

Comment: Better safe than sorry. And when you have your own conversion function, you can easily reuse it at different places.

Comment: I added the code to be used in the SomethingSpecific constructor.

Answer (score 1):

How about a bit more defensive programming? E.g.

```
var s = new Something(uid: row[0] != null ? Convert.ToUInt64(row[0]) : default(UInt64), parentUniqueId: row[1] != null ? Convert.ToUInt64(row[1]) : default(UInt64?));
```

It's not nice but it would do the trick.

Comment: I like this. I think; however, that `default` call _might_ need to be a `null`.

Comment: @Thomas: It will be in the second case. The default is selected based on the type.